# Data Calculator wrong sometimes

Tags: javascript, date-arithmetic

I am working on an open source application and have it running, just ironing out some of the kinks, but am a touch stuck. There is a place where the data is calculated onkeyup and displayed.

The Input and display:

```
<input type="date" class="input-small" name="dob" id="dob"
             onkeyup="showAge();" oninput="showAge();" required
             pattern="^[12]\d{3}-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-([012]?[0-9]|3[01])$"
             data-validation-pattern-message="Must be a valid ISO8601 date."
            placeholder=<?php echo _("YYYY-MM-DD"); ?> 
            value="<?php echo $edata["dob"]; ?>"> 
            <span class="help-inline" id="age">Age: ?</span>
```

The Script:

```
function showAge(ind) {

      document.getElementById('age').innerHTML = "Age: "+
        getAge($('#dob').attr('value'));

  }

  function getAge(a) {
    a = new Date(Date.parse(a.replace(/-/g, "/")));
    var b = new Date, 
      years  = b.getYear () - a.getYear(),
      months = b.getMonth() - a.getMonth(),
      days   = b.getDate () - a.getDate();
    if (b <= a) return "Invalid DOB."
    months < 0 && (years --, months +  12);
    days   < 0 && (months--, days   += 31);
    months < 0 && (years --, months  = 11);

    a = [], b = function(b, c) {
      b > 0 && a.push(b + c + (b > 1 ? "s" : "")) }
    b(years , " year" );
    b(months, " month");
    b(days  , " day"  );
    a.length > 1 && (a[a.length - 1] = "and " + a[a.length - 1]);
    return(!a.length ? "0 days" : "" ) +
      a.join(a.length > 2 ? ", " : " ") + " old."
  }
```

For instance, today is 1/10/2015. If I enter a date of 1/10/2014 it displays Age: 1 Year

If I enter 11/01/2014, it displays 11 Months Old which is wrong, it should be displaying 2 Months.

I have a feeling I am missing something very easy, just don't see it. Help?

Comment: `months + 12` is a no-op.

Comment: It appears you are meaning to do `if` statements for a variety of statements in your code. For example other than: `months < 0 && (years --, months +  12);` you proabally mean: `if(months < 0){  years-- ; months += 12;}`.

Comment: Another point, if this is anything more than a learning project, you should probably use a date library. Calculating dates has a lot of complicated edge cases, your algorithm won't catch any of them.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli - I "leap" to that observation